# Laravel Nullable

Tags: laravel, nullable

I want to ask
How to use a nullable validation in laravel?.
I want to create a new data. So when the data is created, i want the value of the data is still inside the database when there's no value(null) or when there's a value.

Here's the controller code :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'kredit_nik'=>'required|numeric|digits:16',
        'kredit_phone'=>'required|numeric|digits_between:12,15',
        'kredit_phone2'=>'nullable|numeric|digits_between:12,15'
    ]);

    $kredit_nik = $request->kredit_nik;
    $kredit_phone = $request->kredit_phone;
    $kredit_phone2 = $request->kredit_phone2;

    $kredit = new Kredit();
    $kredit->biaya_id = $request->input('biaya');
    $kredit->produk_id = $request->input('produk');
    $kredit->promo_id = $request->input('promo');
    $kredit->kredit_nik = $kredit_nik;
    $kredit->kredit_name = $request->input('kredit_name');
    $kredit->kredit_phone = $kredit_phone;
    $kredit->kredit_phone2 = $kredit_phone2;
    $kredit->kredit_domisili = $request->input('kredit_domisili');
    $kredit->kredit_vehicle = $request->input('kredit_vehicle');
    $kredit->kredit_desc = $request->input('kredit_desc');
    $kredit->save();
    return redirect('/kredit');
    //
}
```

Comment: is this a use to create new data or edit/update the data?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is a useless repetition of the information you've already provided in the tags. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to have meaning to a future user of the site who is skimming through a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn what our expectations are before you begin posting.

Comment: To create new data

Comment: Also, you're not texting your friends here. *wanna* is not a word in the English language. You're not limited in the amount of text you can use. Be clear and specific, and use actual complete words and text to clearly describe the problem you're having and ask a specific question related to the code you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create new data then in your validation, you can just remove this. `'kredit_phone2'=>'nullable|numeric|digits_between:12,15'`

```
    $request->validate([
    'kredit_nik'=>'required|numeric|digits:16',
    'kredit_phone'=>'required|numeric|digits_between:12,15',
]);
```